# play framework server-side redirect on unauthorized async request

Tags: http, redirect, playframework, promise, single-page-application

I am using Play Framework / Reactjs in a single page application.
The authentication is built using ActionBuilders, such that any async request made from the browser is protected by the "AuthorizedAction".

Here is the implementation of the ActionBuiler's `invokeBlock`:

```
override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthorizedRequest[A]) ⇒ Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
  val maybeToken = request.headers.get(AuthTokenHeader).orElse(request.getQueryString(AuthTokenUrlKey))

  maybeToken match {
    case Some(token) => cache.get[Long](token) match {
      case Some(u_id) =>
        val user = User.findByID(u_id).get
        val req = AuthorizedRequest(request, user)
        block(req)
      case None => Future.successful(Unauthorized)  // REDIRECT HERE
    }
    case None => Future.successful(Unauthorized)  // REDIRECT HERE
  }
}
```

This is working great, with one exception: I would like instead of simply returning `Unauthorized` to also redirect to the login page.  Because as of now, if the token times out, and the user causes an async request to be fired, it will simply error out in the console, and the page will look broken.

**method 1:**

replace the two `Future.successful` lines above with:

```
Future.successful(Redirect("/login"))
```

this actually does call the controller for the `/login` route, however the URL does not change. Instead, the response of the async request that was fired contains the data =

```
`<!DOCTYPE html ...
```

Here's an example of async request whose response.data contains the screenshot text below:

```
axios('/ping')
.then((response) => {
  let userID = response.data; // contains junk
  store.dispatch(SomeAction.xyz(userID))
})
.catch((error) => {
  browserHistory.push('/login');
})
```

[image]

Looks like I'm missing something crucial here.  Any ideas how to proceed from here on?

**method 2:**

on the front-end, use React router's `browserHistory.push('/login')`
in all the async requests' `.catch()`

Though I would like to avoid this as much as possible, if method 1 can successfully work.

Thanks

Comment: I'd look at fixing that error that you get from the server (definitely not method 2).

Comment: absolutely. i understand that the redirect is being sent back as a response to the request that caused it.  Remains to figure out how to avoid that behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this has less to do with Play Framework and more with HTTP codes/responses and how they are interpreted by the browser.

It seems we should not return Redirects to async requests, as they would cause the issue of method 1 in the question.

Instead, people have been suggesting one of the following:

- return `Ok/200` with some specific header indicating to the front-end that a redirect must take place
- return some custom error code, e.g. `Status(xyz)` that the front-end code would understand and interpret as a request to redirect to some route.

Choosing the appropriate HTTP code is another topic, and from the two options above, we have three choices:

- `200` or custom `2xx` code, interpreted as a success and handled as such in the promise
- `3xx` custom code, may seem appropriate as we are asking for a redirect
- `401` or custom `4xx` code. Technically, the incoming async request was Unauthorized (401), and so should be an `error` level response.

The crucial part is that handling the response code seems like it will have to be at the front-end, along the lines of method 2 in the question.

I'm leaning towards the default 401